# Console log is telling me that database is locked for many apps. How do I unlock?

Tags: logs, database, sqlite

I'm trying to diagnose a MacMini that is painfully slow to start up.
I already check the filesystem (`fsck`) and the disk (`Disk Warrior`).
I am running High Sierra.

My Mac is fine once it's up and running but something has to be going wrong during boot up.
Looking at the console log, I'm seeing a ton of "database is locked" messages for numerous apps including CalendarAgent, AddressBookSourceSync, soaagent, routined and so forth. Where are these databases and how can I unlock them?

The items I've found online regarding `sqlite` databases have been for Windows and Linux, not finding anything anywhere on this specific issue.

How may I analyse this problem and unlock these databases?

Comment: Sorry --- I left out the obvious --- yes, I did an fsck check as well as some advanced checking with Disk Warrior to make sure the drive itself was ok. Also used Cocktail to do some cleanup, etc.I'm running High Sierra. There are tons of other errors in the logs but I'm trying to go after earlier ones first. I didn't think it made sense to post the entire log from bootup.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue on a relative’s iMac and this worked:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538